# How to convert Curl command to .net HttpClient post call

Tags: c#, .net, curl, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to figure how to convert this curl snippet to the .net HttpClient as a Post request.  Getting 500 error returned from the server from the image below.

Here is the curl command which is for ConvertKit creating a webhook.

```
curl -X POST https://api.convertkit.com/v3/automations/hooks
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json'\
 -d '{ "api_secret": "<your_secret_api_key>",\
       "target_url": "http://example.com/incoming",\
       "event": { "name": "subscriber.subscriber_activate" } }'
```

Link for reference:  http://developers.convertkit.com/#webhooks

Here is my .net code snippet:

```
private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostConverkitCreateWebhookSubscription()
{
        var client = new HttpClient {BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.convertkit.com ") };
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        dynamic event1 = new ExpandoObject();
        event1.name = "subscriber.subscriber_activate";
        var customEvent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(event1);

        var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("api_secret", "<your_secret_api_key>"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("target_url","http://example.com/incoming"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("event", customEvent)
        };

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/v3/automations/hooks")
            {
                Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues)
            };
        return await client.SendAsync(request);
}
```

Getting error 500, so I am probably recky havoc on their servers.

[image]

Could be the JSON object for possible event ...   Not sure.. Need help

Comment: Did you debug the method PostConverkitCreateWebhookSubscription ?

Comment: You wanted to send `application/json`, but you used `FormUrlEncodedContent`. Unless server supports this kind of content type, it might cause 500 error.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, yes it goes through fine, hence that is why it is going to their server and returning a 500 response.  So my data payload must be wrong.  I am just not sure the proper way to convert the .net code to resemble the cUrl code.

Comment: In curl command you are sending data as json while in C# code you are sending as `FormUrlEncodedContent`. You should send as Json in C# too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormUrlEncodedContent` encodes key-value pairs similar to a query string. You're basically telling it to send URL-encoded key-value pairs, where the last value is JSON encoded. So your request body will look something like this:

`api_secret=<your_secret_api_key>&target_url=http://example.com/incoming&event={"name":"subscriber.subscriber_activate"}`

But the API expects the entire payload to be JSON encoded. This modified version should do the trick:

```
var data = new
{
    api_secret = "<your_secret_api_key>",
    target_url = "http://example.com/incoming",
    @event = new
    {
        name = "subscriber.subscriber_activate"
    }
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data); // json-encode everything, not just event

var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.convertkit.com ") };
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
return await client.PostAsync("/v3/automations/hooks", content);
```

As a side note, `event` is a reserved word in C#; `@event` is how you escape it in order to use it as a property name.